# Question on GNOME Shell theme editing

Tags: 11.10, gnome, css, editing

I know nothing about CSS, but with a little help, I managed to make the activites button in Shell to display the ubuntu icon. It's great, works good with most all themes.

[image]

Except for one part. There is a small gap between the Ubuntu Icon and the icon for the current application (left of the mouse in the second picture).

[image]

I know that it wouldn't bother anyone besides me, but when it comes to my desktop I have OCD and need to find a way to get that gap smaller. Is there any way to get the small little area even smaller? Any number I can edit in the CSS file?
I use the icon on Zukiwito-Shell and Faience shell themes, but I believe my problem would be the same with just stock default theme.
The line I add is the one highlighted in this pic (I manually add image.png in the folder of the theme)

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Reduce the width and try adding the following to your css.

```
width: 30px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto
```

Comment: Where would I place that in the file?

Comment: Right in line where it is now. You used an image so I could not copy-paste. On the line with the 'url' to the image file, with all the other options `border: none; backgroung-image: ... width: 30px; display: block; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; ... color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` You can increase readability if you wish by writing one css property per line. FWIW : http://www.w3schools.com/css/